# MLNET to VOTT(active learning)

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, visual-studio-2022, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I have some problem with Visual Studio 2022 Model builder. As microsoft recommended the object detection model builder is VOTT. In VOTT it can label all the image pretty well. But about Active Learning I see that it can import local model to VOTT. I am successfully label and trained data which give me an output of .MLNET file type. And the project automatically generate the code for C# consoleapp which have around 3 classes

```
 1. program.cs
 2. consume.cs
 3. training.cs
```

`The question is how can I export this MLNET file type to VOTT Active Learning`

I have done some research it says that VOTT Active learning require Tensorflow.js.

`So in another question is how to convert MLNET to tensorflow.js`

PS. Please correct me if I am wrong. I cant find too much information on this. Also I can’t find any .zip file type in directory of project. Just .MLNET

My goal is to import MLNET to help for labelling image in VOTT with active learning.

Thanks